# sas proc sql escape ' (apostrophe)

Tags: sql, sas

Is it possible to put an apostrophe into the label when using proc sql?

```
proc sql;
    create table palim
    as select palim label='palim's palim'
    from palim;
quit;
```

This will not work, because sas thinks the apostrohe is the end of the label.

I did not manage to get it to work with `escape`  [sas community question](https://communities.sas.com/t5/Base-SAS-Programming/proc-sql-escape-character/td-p/242283)

This questions is specifically for proc sql, since using double quotes will not work here.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to escape the ' character in sas](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23106014/how-to-escape-the-character-in-sas)

Comment: @craigcaulfield this is to some extent a douplicate, but the accepted answer of the question you posted is not working here. The second answer would have worked. You want me to delete it?

Comment: No. Looks like there's more than one way to handle apostrophes in labels.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `%` to escape single quote.

```
proc sql;
    create table palim
    as select palim label='palim%'s palim'
    from palim;
quit;
```

Can also uso double single quote.

```
proc sql;
    create table palim
    as select palim label='palim''s palim'
    from palim;
quit;
```

The `escape` clause works `LIKE` expressions.

Comment: Thank you, double ``''`` makes sense and does indeed work

Comment: You can also double quote as such `lable="palim's palim"`.  Be aware that macro will process % and & inside double quote.

Comment: % does not work to escape the single quote.  `label='palim%'s palim'` will create an unmatched quote problem.  In the macro language, % can be used to mask a single quote when used with the `%STR()` quoting function.

Answer (score 1):

Either switch to using double quote character `"` to quote your string literal so that the character used on the outside is not contained in the string.

```
label="palim's palim"
```

Or double up any embedded quote characters that match the character used on the outside.

```
label='palim''s palim'
```

You can use either single or double quote characters to quote string literals in SAS.  The only reason they would not work in `PROC SQL` would be if you added the `dquote=ansi` option to the `proc sql` statement.  Then values inside double quotes are interpreted as names instead of string literals.